# Multiple jQuery AJAX calls conflicts?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a simple shopping cart using AJAX and PHP.

Everything works as it should BUT 1 thing doesn't work all the time and it seems that it fails to execute. **(it works 3 times out of 5).**

to explain this issue please take a look at the code bellow:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

//////////////////////LETS RUN OUR ADD TO CART FEATURE USING AJAX //////////////    
$(function(){   
    $('.form1').on('submit', function(e){
        $( "#preloader" ).fadeIn( 850 );


        // prevent native form submission here
        e.preventDefault();

        // now do whatever you want here


        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),// <-- get method of form
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            //url: "cart.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(), // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(data){
                $( "#preloader" ).fadeOut( 850 );

            }
        });
    });


    });


//////////////////////LETS RUN LOAD THE cart-header.php ON PAGE LOAD USING AJAX //////////////  
$(document).ready(function () { 
    function load1() {
        $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "cart-header.php",
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
            success: function (data2) {
                $('#headerCart').html($(data2));



                //setTimeout(load2, 500);


            }

        });

    }

load1();
});

//////////////////////LETS LOAD THE cart-header.php on form1 submit USING AJAX //////////////   

<!----- This is the part that SOMETIMES Fails to work --->


    $(function(){   
    $('.form1').on('submit', function(load2){




        // prevent native form submission here
        load2.preventDefault();

        // now do whatever you want here


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",// <-- get method of form
            url: "cart-header.php",
            //url: "cart.php",
            dataType: "html", // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(data){

                //$('#test').load('cart.php #total').html();

                $('#headerCart').html($(data));





            }
        });
    });


    });


//////////////////////LETS RUN OUR DELETE FROM CART FEATURE USING AJAX //////////////       


$(document).on('submit', '.delForm', function(dleItem){


        // prevent native form submission here
        dleItem.preventDefault();

        // now do whatever you want here


        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),// <-- get method of form
            url: "cart-header.php",
            //url: "cart.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(), // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(data){
$('#headerCart').html($(data));
            }
        });
    });




});


//////////////////////LETS GET THE QUANTITY OF CURRENT ITEMS ADDED IN THE CART USING AJAX/////////////


$(document).ready(function () {

    function load() {
        $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "cart.php",
            //url: "cart-header.php",
            dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
            success: function (data) {
                $('.item_count').html($(data).find('#total').text());
                //$('#headerCart').html($(data));



                setTimeout(load, 1000);


            }

        });
    }

    load();

});
```

I have commented the code so you can see the parts of the code and what they do.

**the issue is this part:**

```
//////////////////////LETS LOAD THE cart-header.php on form1 submit USING AJAX //////////////   

<!----- This is the part that SOMETIMES Fails to work --->


    $(function(){   
    $('.form1').on('submit', function(load2){




        // prevent native form submission here
        load2.preventDefault();

        // now do whatever you want here


        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",// <-- get method of form
            url: "cart-header.php",
            //url: "cart.php",
            dataType: "html", // <-- serialize all fields into a string that is ready to be posted to your PHP file
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(data){

                //$('#test').load('cart.php #total').html();

                $('#headerCart').html($(data));





            }
        });
    });


    });
```

As I mentioned above, this code works fine but it only works when it wants to as if it has mind of its own!

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `dataType: "html"` is because ajax is expected a result in `html` format. and you are calling a function `load1();` in the success function, which is in a scope of a different doc ready. Instead put that in the global scope.

Comment: @Jai, i just put that there as a test. I can remove that and still does the same thing (works when it wants to).